# I want to animate dust particles in a cave that forms a word then disperse again

Tags: after-effects, effects

[image]

I know this is probably related to the particle system in after effect, but all the youtube videos I have seen used a few thousand particles at once to do this. Is there a way to only use a few circles to roughly form the shape of the letter "I" instead of actually turning it into the actual text? I would also like to make the circles vibrate slightly while it is in its letter "I" form.